# Issues with custom UITableViewCells in Storyboard

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I need to create a custom `UITableViewCell` that displays four `UILabel` instances.

In the implementation of this custom cell, I have the following initialization code:

```
- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
    if (self) {
        // configure labels
        self.positionLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(5, 10, 300, 30)];
        self.positionLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
        self.positionLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica Neue" size:14.0f];

        [self addSubview:self.positionLabel];
    }
    return self;
}
```

In my `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method, I have the following code to

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    CustomUICell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"CELL"];

    if (cell == nil) {
         cell = [[CustomUICell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"CELL"];

        cell.positionLabel.text = @"Test";

    }
    [cell setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];

    return cell;
}
```

However, instead of creating the cells with `initWithFrame:CGRectMake(5, 10, 300, 30)];`, I would prefer to do this in my storyboard. If I drag a label onto my cell in the storyboard, and connect it to the appropriate property as below:

```
@property (nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *positionLabel;
```

and create my label by writing:

```
self.positionLabel = [[UILabel alloc] init];
```

I would expect to see a label in my cell when I run my app, but that doesn't happen. Does anyone have any insight into what I'm missing / not understanding? Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, use `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:forIndexPath:` instead of `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:`. In this case you don't need the `if` clause.

About your question: When you add the cell in a storyboard, you don't need to implement `initWithStyle:reuseIdentifier:`. In fact, if you do, the code path is executed and overrides everything you do in the storyboard.

Comment: That makes sense @dasdom, thank you. The reason I had put things in `initWithStyle:reuseIdentifier`was that when I added my label to the storyboard, it wouldn't show up at all.

Comment: Use `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:forIndexPath:` and make sure to use the same cell identifier.